# How does passing by reference really work in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, function, pass-by-reference

I am wondering how passing by reference works in C#. If I pass a WPF DataGrid control by reference to a function, and slowly have the function add items to its DataGrid.Items collection, will the DataGrid in the UI update with each new DataGrid.Items.Add() call?  Or will it only update when the function returns?  I would like to achieve the former scenario, so if passing by reference doesn't do the trick, I would love some advice on how to accomplish this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

if u want the former scenario, then call the function UpdateLayout() of datagrid in the next statement after you use Add() method. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

Passing by reference is irrelevant to your situation anyway. Passing by reference (i.e. `ref`) allows you to assign to the variable in the calling scope. You are not trying to do that. You only want to access the `DataGrid` reference and access its `Items` field. That does not require `ref` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an extension to what Ethicallogics said I would subclass and override add so that it calls UpdateLayout each time, then you don't have to worry about it.

In general it's good to subclass all the .net classes [specifically for anything UI related] you will need, that way if you run into custom requirements you don't have to do it later.  Use your own subclasses at all times.