# How does passing by reference in vb.net done?

Tags: vb.net

This question is similar to [How does passing by reference really work in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346809/how-does-passing-by-reference-really-work-in-c)

However, the detail is different. This one I really just want to know how it's implemented.

There are 2 opinions.

Pass by reference is done similarly with C++. Namely we're actually passing a pointer that's automatically referenced.

Also special for object, in vb.net, passed by reference means we're actually passing a pointer to a pointer and automatically dereference one of them.

That's one explanation.

Another explanation is that passed by reference is actually similar to pass by value except that when the function return, any change is copied back to the paramater.

Which one is right?

Is it the same whether we pass an object or a basic type like integer, string, double, etc.?

Is it so "implementation dependent" that there is no way to know which one is which?

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing a value then passing by reference is like passing a pointer to that value.  If you're passing a reference, which is basically a tarted-up pointer, then passing by reference is like passing a pointer to a pointer.

Passing a value type by value means that no changes made inside the method affect the original variable.

Passing a value type by reference means that no changes made to the argument affect the original but assigning a new value to the parameter does affect the original.

Passing a reference type by value means that any changes made to the argument do affect the original but assigning a new object to the parameters does not affect the original.

Passing a reference type by reference means that all changes made inside the method affect the original.